# Cursor.getColumnIndex() returns -1 for a column that exists

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm writing code that will upgrade my app's database to a new version. While upgrading, I drop a table and re-create it with a different schema (including a new column). When I attempt to read data from this new table, I create a cursor like so:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ALARMS, null);
```

And when I try to read data from the new column, cursor.getColumnIndex(NEW_COLUMN) returns -1, meaning it doesn't exist. This isn't correct as the new column is included in the new schema. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with the column, you can verify that by `getColumnNames()` or `getColumnCount()` on your `Cursor`.

What's missing is the index of your `Cursor`, as stated in [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) documentation the return value is,

> A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry.

So initially it is not valid and you need to do a `moveFirst()` or a `moveNext()` before accessing data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I had a problem where my cursor wouldnt read all entrys of a table ( the ones i just create didnt work ) i solved it by closing the cursor and reopening it try that :)

Comment: I don't think I can close/reopen the database in the onUpgrade() method but I tried it with the cursor and so far it seemed to work.

Comment: Wait im stupid remembered this wrong I only updated the cursor meh xD

Comment: Unfortunately it's consistent. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. If I put the cursor open/close in a while loop it's never resolved either.